# passing address to kfree

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

If we allocate memory by `kmalloc()`, then while freeing memory should i pass only starting address of memory block to `kfree()` or any address with in the allocated memory block?

For ex: in the below program, will `kfree()` be able to free the `1KB` memory allocated?

```
        int my_kmalloc_init(void) 
 {

        kp = kmalloc(1024,GFP_KERNEL);
        if(!kp) {
                pr_err("memory allocation failed");
                return -ENOMEM;
        }

        return 0;
}

void my_kmalloc_exit(void) {

        kfree(kp+100);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already stated, you should pass a pointer to the exact address that was returned to you by the allocator, let me explain a bit further why you need this.

When you call an allocator, it'll search in a 'pool' for some block of memory that's good for your request but how does the allocator know what's the size each block? It keeps it, typically, right before the pointer that's passed to you.

This area is important for allocator because of two reasons: In there, there's a flag that indicates whether this block is allocated or not + the size of block (and maybe other things).

When you call the free function, the allocator needs to know the size of the block you wanna free and it needs to mark it as free so it assumes that in a certain area before the address you gave, it can check/set these information; so no, giving it the address of middle of the object screws things up for your allocator.

Answer (score 1):

Just as with `malloc()` and `free()`, `kfree()` must be passed the exact address that was returned by `kmalloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

No matter kernel uses slob, slab or slub allocator, all treat the allocated memory as a whole object. So, you can't free only a part of it.

- [SLAB Allocator](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand011.html)
- [SLUB Allocator](http://lwn.net/Articles/229984/)
- [SLOB Allocator](http://lwn.net/Articles/157944/)